# How to implement retry mechanism in function using boolean flag

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, java-8

### What I want to do:

I want to implement a retry mechanism for function `checkExpiryForADate`. There is one part within function `checkExpiryForADate` where we will call `externalService.getRecord`, which could return an empty list.

If this is the case, I want to rerun the function every 10 min until it does not return an empty list (Once externalService.getRecord does not return an empty list when we run `checkExpiryForADate`, we would not run it anymore within the scheduled timeframe (from 7AM to 9AM)

I have changed `checkExpiryForADate` to be like this to implement the retry mechanism

### What I have tried:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler: */10 7-8 * * MON-FRI}")
public void loadAndCheckExpiry() {
  boolean checkedRecordIsAvailable = false; //initialise the flag as false
  if (!checkedRecordIsAvailable) { //if flag is false, run `checkExpiryForADate`
      checkedRecordIsAvailable = checkExpiryForADate(dateService.today()); //update flag's value
  }
}

public boolean checkExpiryForADate(LocalDate asOf)
{
    Collection<Product> listOfProducts = productService.getProducts(asOf)

    for (Product product : listOfProducts) {

        //What I want to do here is that: if 1 of the products couldn't get `expiryRecord` in the `checkExpiry` function, 
        then we return false for the this `checkExpiryForADate` function

        if (!checkExpiry(product, asOf) {
            //get out of the for loop
            return false;
        }
    }

private boolean checkExpiry(Product product, LocalDate asOf) {
    //code to perform some operations - omitted

    List<Pair<ZonedDateTime, Double>> expiryRecords = new ArrayList<>(externalService.getRecord());
    if (expiryRecords.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    
    //code to perform some operations - omitted
    return true;
}
```

### The problem with my code:

1. In the `loadAndCheckExpiry` function, whenever the function is being run, checkedRecordIsAvailable will be initialised to false again. Is it that I should put the flag outside of the `loadAndCheckExpiry`? If so, it could be updated to true between 7-8AM (the schedule) - but I need to set it to false again everyday for the next day.
2. Is it a correct way for me to update the flag using this code `checkedRecordIsAvailable = checkExpiryForADate(dateService.today());`? (When `checkExpiryForADate` returns true, the boolean `checkedRecordIsAvailable` will indeed be updated?

   In addition, There is a warning of `redundant assignment` saying that the value `checkExpiryForADate(dateService.today())` assigned to `checkedRecordIsAvailable` is never used. But I think I am using it in a `if` statement?
3. In `checkExpiryForADate`, if for either 1 of the product in`checkExpiry(product, asOf)` returns false, then I want to break out of the for loop and return false for `checkExpiryForADate` directly. Is this the correct way to do it?
4. In general, I think my code is very cumbersome, I wonder if there is any more elegant way to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is similar to [How to implement retry mechanism with exception and try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746053/how-to-implement-retry-mechanism-with-exception-and-try-catch), here is a possible solution:

Defining `lastSucess` instead of `checkedRecordIsAvailable` as the flag for checking, outside of the `loadAndCheckExpiry` function:

```
private Long lastSuccess = null;
```

`loadAndCheckExpiry`:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler: */10 7-8 * * MON-FRI}")
public void loadAndCheckExpiry() {
    if (!sameDate(lastSuccess, System.currentTimeMillis())) { //if flag is false, run `checkExpiryForADate`
        checkExpiryForADate(dateService.today()); //update flag's value
    }
}
```

`checkExpiryForADate`, breaking the loop if `checkExpiry` returns `false` for any product, setting `lastSuccess` to current time if every products passes `checkExpiry`:

```
private void checkExpiryForADate(LocalDate asOf){
    Collection<Product> listOfProducts = productService.getProducts(asOf);
    for (Product product : listOfProducts) {
        if (!checkExpiry(product, asOf)) return;
    }
    lastSuccess = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

`checkExpiry`:

```
private boolean checkExpiry(Product product, LocalDate asOf) {
    // your code ...
    List<Pair<ZonedDateTime, Double>> expiryRecords = new ArrayList<>(externalService.getRecord());

    // your code ...
    return !expiryRecords.isEmpty();
}
```

`sameDate` for checking two `Long` values to be within the same date, returning `false` if either value is `null`:

```
private Boolean sameDate(Long d1, Long d2){
    if(d1 == null || d2 == null) return false;
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(d1);
    cal2.setTimeInMillis(d2);
    return cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) &&
                            cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Hope it can help a bit.