# How to implement retry mechanism with exception and try catch

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, java-8, retry-logic

### What I want to do:

I want to implement a retry mechanism for function `dailyComputeValue`. `dailyComputeValue` will call `computeValue`. There is one part within function `ComputeValue` where we will call `externalService.getRecord`, which could return an empty list.

If this is the case, I want to rerun the function every 10 min until it does not return an empty list (Once externalService.getRecord does not return an empty list when we run `checkExpiryForADate`, we would not run it anymore within the scheduled timeframe (from 7AM to 9AM)

The complication is that I cannot use a boolean flag in this case because `computeValue` needs to return a `double`. So I am thinking of throwing an exception if `externalService.getRecord` returns an empty list.
I have changed `dailyComputeValue` to be like the code below to implement the retry mechanism

### What I have tried:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler: */10 7-8 * * MON-FRI}")
public void dailyComputeValue() {
  double value = 0;
  try {
      value = computeValue(String product);
  } 
  catch {
     log.warn("Record not available yet", ex.getMessage();)
  }
  //to only save to database if there is good value (not from the empty list)
  valueRepository.save(value);
}

public Double computeValue(String product)
{
    List<Pair<ZonedDateTime, Double>> valueRecords = new ArrayList<>(externalService.getRecord());
    if (valueRecords.isEmpty()){
    throw new Exception("Record not available yet");
    }
    //perform some operation to return a double
}
```

### The problem with my code:

The current code will retry `computeValue` every 10 minutes, but will not stop once computeValue returns a double. I am not sure how to implement the code to "rerun the function every 10 min until it does not return an empty list (Once externalService.getRecord does not return an empty list when we run `dailyComputeValue`, we would not run it anymore within the scheduled timeframe (from 7AM to 9AM)".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can use `while` loop inside `try` block with `10` minutes sleep time when `externalService.getRecord()` return empty list. And make `computeValue` method to return `null` if empty list is returned by `externalService.getRecord()`

In this case you can keep the scheduler to run between 7AM to 9AM

```
 double value = null;

 try {

     while(value == null) {

        value = computeValue(String product);

        if(value == null){
           Thread.sleep(10) //minutes
        }
     }
  } 
    catch {
      log.warn("Record not available yet", ex.getMessage();)
  }
```

You can also check [Spring Retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) but you have to specify the max number of retries and you can keep it `Integer.MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your question, here is one possible solution.

```
private double value = null;
private long lastSuccess;

@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler: */10 7-8 * * MON-FRI}")
public void dailyComputeValue() {

  if(value != null && 
     lastSuccess != null && 
     !sameDate(lastSuccess, System.currentTimeMillis()){
     // resetting value in new day
     value = null;
  }
  
  if(value != null) return; // skipping scheduled job if value is present

  try {
     value = computeValue(String product);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     log.warn("Record not available yet", ex.getMessage();)
     return;
  }

  lastSuccess = System.currentTimeMillis();
  valueRepository.save(value);
}
```

Checking same date:

```
private Boolean sameDate(long d1, long d2){
  Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal1.setTimeInMillis(d1);
  cal2.setTimeInMillis(d2);
  return cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) &&
                        cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Hope it is of some help.